# VBA - Open files in folder and print names

Tags: vba, excel, printing, directory

I want to open all of the files in a certain folder and have it print out the names of those files.

I have set up a code that opens the files but I cannot get it to print the name. I have a separate code that will print the name but will only open one file. I'm failing at combining the two together correctly. Any ideas?

**Code that opens all Excel files:**

```
‘set path to progress folder
Sub OpenFiles()
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
MyFolder = “C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xlsx")
Do While MyFile <> ""
Workbooks.Open fileName:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile
    MyFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

**Code that prints one file name:**

```
'set path to TDS_Working
Sub TDS()
    Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress")
End Sub

'set up dim
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object

Dim i As Integer

'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\")
i = 1
'loop through directory file and print names
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    'print file name
    Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name
Next objFile
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work smoothly :

```
   Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer

    MyFolder = "C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\"

Set Sht = ActiveSheet

    'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)
    i = 1
    'loop through directory file and print names
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

        If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) <> "xls" And LCase(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 4), 3)) <> "xls" Then
        Else
            'print file name
            Sht.Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name
            i = i + 1
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & objFile.Name
        End If
    Next objFile

    End Sub
```

Comment: I get back an error message saying that the code is trying to alter the cells (my Excel documents are in protected mode so that they cannot be changed). Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Either Unprotect manually in Excel, or add `Cells.Unprotect` above the `Cells(i + 1, 1) = ...` statement

Comment: Created an error so I used ActiveSheet.Unprotect. However this still only printed one name from my list of Excel files

Comment: @R3uK, using an unqualified call to `Cells` while opening `Workbooks` is doomed if you want the output in the first file that was open.  Save a reference to the first sheet `Set sht = ActiveSheet` and use it later on `sht.Cells`.

Comment: Indeed @Byron , I forgot to check that as I was just compiling the two subs

Comment: You're incredible @R3uK!! Thank you so much I really appreciate it. Clearly you've done enough so if you want to ignore this no worries and I'll try to look it up myself, but if you had a spare second to explain what exactly this section means so I could better understand what you did, that'd be wonderful too.

 If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) <> "xls" And LCase(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 4), 3)) <> "xls" Then
        Else
            'print file name
            Sht.Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name
            i = i + 1
            Workbooks.Open FileName:=MyFolder & objFile.Name
        End If

Comment: No problem mate, this is what this site is for! ;) if you can just validate answer (tick under up and down vote) to show your issue as solved, it would be nice! For the part, it test the extension of the file to only try to open Excel files, then write the file's name I the correct sheet, and open the workbook with full path (like `C:\...\*.xls*`)

Answer (score 1):

```
‘set path to progress folder
Sub OpenFiles()
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("password")
MyFolder = “C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xlsx")
i=1
Do While MyFile <> ""
Workbooks.Open fileName:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile
    MyFile = Dir
    Cells(i + 1, 1) =Myfile
    i=i+1
Loop
ActiveSheet.Protect ("password")
End Sub
```

Does this not work?

Comment: This tries to alter the cells of my excel document that I am just trying to extract info from, not change

Comment: My excel files are protected...would that affect it?

Comment: so you are trying to read from the sheet? Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name would put the name inside that cell? if your sheet is protected you only need to unprotect if you want to write the filenames onto the sheet.

Comment: I will eventually try to read from the sheet but currently am just trying to figure out how to get the file to open as well as add the file name to a column in a "master sheet", if you will. I believe it would only come back as an Error: this sheeet is protected message if the file I'm trying to open is trying to be changed in some way... Any ideas how to just get the file names?

Comment: The workbook that the macro is running from(Hence forth called Master Workbook) is giving you that message because the code is trying to write "MyFile" to "cells(i+1,1)". To get around the protection error you would have to unprotect the master workbook/sheet and then reprotect after this has finished. I have addressed protection in my code above

Comment: I tried your code and still come up with the same error message. It looks like it should work, I can't figure out why it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

You just need to iterate i inside the loop: `i=i+1`.

Comment: I do have i+1 inside of one of the loops. Could you be more specific as to which line you are referring to?

I hav been trying to troubleshoot it with i+1 but cannot seem to find the right way to put it into my code.

Comment: First, you are not using this equation in your posted code. I am not referring to inside the `Cells()`. Specifically, in your second example using FSO, place `i = i +1` inside the For Loop after the Cells line.